# Magento 2 - Creating a new store view throws error - Integrity constraint violation

Tags: magento2, database, error, store-view, unique-constraint

I need to create a new store view, but I get this error:

**Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'studioline-4' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID'**

I checked the database, but there is only one entry for studioline

[image]

What can I do? Why is the error thrown?

I also deleted the "studioline" entry from the database, but I get the same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two CMS sites with the same URL-Key. I had to change the URL Key for one of them or delete one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do re-indexing after deleting the duplicate entry from database.

**Below are the step for reindexing via Magento 2 Admin**

- Log in to Magento 2 Admin and navigate to System → Index Management. You will see the panel above.
- Select indexers, which has status Reindex Required, then select in Actions menu Update on Schedule.
- Press Submit button to apply selected mode to indexers.

  ```
   OR
  ```

**Reindexing via command line**

- bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: It was not helping, I still get the error.